# How can I exclude matched terms from prefix searching in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, match, prefix

Is there any way how to tell Elastic to exclude matched terms for "prefix" searching?

Consider this query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": {"title": "word1"}},
                {"match": {"title": "word2"}},
                {"prefix": {"title": "w"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and stored documents in an index:

```
{"title": "word1 word2", "data": "..."}
{"title": "word2 word1", "data": "..."}
{"title": "word1 word2 www", "data": "..."}
{"title": "word1 www word2", "data": "..."}
{"title": "www word2 word1", "data": "..."}
{"title": "xxx www word2 word1", "data": "..."}
```

then all these documents will be in query response (because terms "word1", "word2" and "www" has "w" prefix).

But that's not ok for me. I need to obtain only these documents:

```
{"title": "word1 word2 www", "data": "..."}
{"title": "word1 www word2", "data": "..."}
{"title": "www word2 word1", "data": "..."}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What is it exactly that you want ? title containing **only** `word1` `word2` and another word starting with `w` but distinct from `word1` and `word2` ? Using `prefix` query you won't be able to remove `word1` and `word2` as they start with `w`, you will need to use a regexp which is much more costly.

Comment: sorry, i need to obtain these documents:
```
{"title": "word1 word2 www", "data": "..."}
{"title": "word1 www word2", "data": "..."}
{"title": "www word2 word1", "data": "..."}
{"title": "xxx www word2 word1", "data": "..."}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output you mentioned, you need `word1`, `word2` and `www` to be all present in the title.

For `prefix` matching, you need to match it with `title.keyword` and not `title` since the inverted index does contain atleast one work with `w` as prefix. But as i understand, you want the prefix for the entire title so `keyword` should achieve that.

Below query works and gives expected results:

```
{
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "title": "word1"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "title": "word2"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "title": "www"
              }
            },
            {
              "prefix": {
                "title.keyword": "w"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```